# Unable to apply jQuery functions to a JSON generated comparison table

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I'm trying to create a comparison table basis the selected inputs from a multi-select dropdown. The data to populate the table resides in a separate .json file.

While the table is building as expected, for some reason it doesn't allow me to apply jQuery functionalities to the table. When I try to use a jQuery plugin or code to custom-format the table it basis the value of the cell, I'm unable to do so.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/0b64s8ka/9/

The JSON Array:

```
var StatJSON = {
  "Samsung": {
    "Parameter1": "<div id=\"rating1\"> 40 </div>",
    "Parameter2": "<div id=\"rating2\"> 50 </div>",
    "Parameter3": "<div id=\"rating3\"> 30 </div>"
  },
  "Mi": {
    "Parameter1": "<div id=\"rating1\"> 40 </div>",
    "Parameter2": "<div id=\"rating2\"> 50 </div>",
    "Parameter3": "<div id=\"rating3\"> 30 </div>"
  },
  "Apple": {
    "Parameter1": "<div id=\"rating1\"> 50 </div>",
    "Parameter2": "<div id=\"rating2\"> 30 </div>",
    "Parameter3": "<div id=\"rating3\"> 40 </div>"
  }  
};
```

The jQuery code I'm using to generate the table basis the selections made by the user:

```
jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
 var data = [];  
 jQuery("#selection").find(':selected').each(function(e) {
   var this_input = jQuery(this);
   if (this_input.is(':selected')) {
     data.push(this_input.val());
   }
 });
 $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));
});

function PrintTable(data) {
  var html = '<table class="compTable"><tr><td>';
  if (data && data.length) {
    html += '</td>';
    jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
      html += '<td id="myHeader" class="header2">' + v + '</td>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
    jQuery.each(StatJSON[data[0]], function(k, v) {
      html += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td>';
        jQuery.each(data, function(k2, v2) {
        html += '<td>' + StatJSON[data[k2]][k] + '</td>';
      });
      html += '</tr>';
    });
  } else { html += 'No results found</td></tr>'; }
  html += '</table>';
  return html;
}
});
```

Some of the jQuery (example) to target the table:

```
jQuery('#myHeader tr td').each(function($){
  if($(this).text() == 'Samsung')$(this).css("background-color","red");
  if($(this).text() == 'Mi')$(this).css("background-color","blue");
  if($(this).text() == 'Apple')$(this).css("background-color","green");
});

jQuery('#rating1 tr td').each(function($){
  if($(this) = '40')$(this).css("background-color","red");
  if($(this) = '30')$(this).css("background-color","blue");
  if($(this) = '50')$(this).css("background-color","green");
});
```

Óne of the plugins that I'm trying to use to format the table is the rating-bar plugin from github: https://github.com/mre/jquery.ratingbar/

This plugin requires me to encode the value in the JSON with a div:

```
<div class="rating">80</div>
```

The jquery required is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.rating').ratingbar();
    });
```

But the jquery doesn't execute when I encode the value in the JSON with a div. How do I do this?

Comment: I deleted my answer because you have just too much stuff going on wrong. You are using `.each()` wrong, `$(this)` wrong, assign operator instead of comparison operator, and the rating1... ID's are not unique. There are no elements with class `.rating` also. When you apply the `ratingbar()`, you do this on document ready, so you might have race conditions there, too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make following changes in your code

1: Correct usage of comparison operator. It should be == and not = . (The fiddle itself is indicating an error for it).

2: User jQuery in place of $. (Always check developer console to catch such issues)

3: Run you Jquery snippet on elements, only after the elements are addd to DOM. you are creating element using PrintTable method so any operation on those elements should be done after that only.

I have taken your fiddle and corrected it for one example.

https://jsfiddle.net/v0yq4hft/

```
jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
 var data = [];  
 jQuery("#selection").find(':selected').each(function(e) {
   var this_input = jQuery(this);
   if (this_input.is(':selected')) {
     data.push(this_input.val());
   }
 });
 $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));


jQuery('#divResult table tr td').each(function($){
  console.log(jQuery(this));
  if(jQuery(this).text() == 'Samsung')jQuery(this).css("background-color","red");
  if(jQuery(this).text() == 'Mi')jQuery(this).css("background-color","blue");
  if(jQuery(this).text() == 'Apple')jQuery(this).css("background-color","green");
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Deep!! That solved my heading issue. However, when I tried a similar approach with the values in my table, where I require to apply a 'rating' class from a plugin I have used. .  My code : `jQuery('#mytable table tr td').each(function($){
  if(jQuery(k2) == 'Parameter1')jQuery(v2).css("rating");
  if(jQuery(k2) == 'Parameter2')jQuery(v2).css("rating");`, but this didn't work. I have cleaned up the code a bit in the JSfiddle, please do check this and let me know how I should be approaching it. Thanks a million, again!! Upd.Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/sxg8u5mt/10/

Comment: @MithunUchil what plugin url are you using for rating bar ? i don't see any plugin resource added in your fiddle.

Comment: Hi @Deep. Sorry, I thought I had saved the resource in the fiddle but it wasn't showing. Have updated the fiddle. It's the following plugin: https://github.com/mre/jquery.ratingbar. Have updated the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/sxg8u5mt/12/  it should show now. Thanks again!!

Comment: @MithunUchil you are applying the plugin before creating the elements with rating class. You need to first assign all td element the required class and then apply the plugin. https://jsfiddle.net/qutzsjob/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Deep!!! Amazing job!! I'm a newbie here, wish I could up-vote your answer and comments but don't think I have enough points to yet to make the cut!! But would definitely refer you to anyone looking for someone with your expertise!